# How to add vm_args for a java web application to run on tomcat added using community server connector in vscode

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, visual-studio-code, tomcat

I have added community server connector as Tomcat in vscode. and now my application needs vm_args to run. i have tried adding arguments using setenv.sh file in bin folder.

Tried below approach and it did not work.

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS \
-Druntime.context.environmentType=dev \

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS \
-Druntime.context.environmentType=dev \
```

but when i run catalina.sh from terminal it shows it is reading from setenv.sh file and shows arguments i have passed. but my application is not getting vm args to run.